# Firefox 57: How to get a new tab be a blank page?

Tags: firefox

Firefox did an update on itself. I have now found the checkbox to stop that. But the latest version (57) has a not-so-charming feature. When I open a new tab, I get some wierd page like an ad for facebook and a bunch of other crud. I've tried two add-ons to make new tabs be a blank page, neither works. How can one open a new tab and get a blank page?

Comment: I find this question useful, as there is almost no other place where this is being asked. Although I agree that maybe SuperUser would be a better place for the question over StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

New tab page, options button at upper right corner. Customize display.

Comment: It is not the same. Yes, you can remove all items from there, but it is still not the same. For example, the firefox-logo favicon is still there, and if you have a lot of opened tabs and use empty tabs to separate them, now they look like Mozilla pages, not empty tab pages. So, is there any way (like an about:config pref or something similar) of getting an empty `about:blank` page when opening a new tab?

Comment: Sez "closed" but here's a point: Firefox 69 now has this fixed, can open a new tab to a blank page.